# list field inserted to api with postman returns ok, in heroku deployed api field is empty

Tags: java, spring, api, hibernate, heroku

Im building an api rest with spring jpa and angular. This api has a list field "tags" that is posted correctly with postman with POST method:

[image]

BUT when I go to my api deployed in heroku, tags field is empty:

```
{"id":3164,"name":"Iñaki","surname":"Williams","dni":"19238191G","address":"calle almanaque,Madrid","mail":"williams@iñaqui.com","phone":"9373482382","linkedln":"https://www.linkedin.com/
```

in/sara-b-54b93543/","state":"por validar","rating":"67","availability":"tardes","tags":[]}]

My experts model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="experts")
public class Expert {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String dni;
    private String address;
    private String mail;
    private String phone;
    private String linkedln;
    private String state;
    private String rating;
    private String availability;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="expert", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();


    public Expert() {
    }

    public Expert(String name, String surname, String dni, String address, String mail, String phone, String linkedln, String state, String rating, List<Tag> tags, String availability) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.address = address;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.linkedln = linkedln;
        this.state = state;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.availability = availability;
    }
```

My tags model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tags")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
           name = "experts_tags",
           joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
           inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="expert_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
   )
    private List<Expert> expert = new ArrayList<>();

    public Tag() {
    }
```

postExpert method in expertDAO:

```
   @Override
    public Expert postExpert(Expert expert) {
         this.manager.persist(expert);
         return expert;
    }
```

any idea why this is happening?? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you do a @ManyToMany field on entity , it creates a third table that maps between the two , i suggest that you do the following :

- Create a new class called `Response`
- This class will have the same attributes as `Expert` but without any annotation ( its not an entity )
- Each time you have an `Expert` instance , create a `Response` instance which takes the same values
- On your RestController , make the method that returns a list of `Expert` class return a list of `Response` instead , which you will fill with `Response` instances

  ```
   public class Response {

   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   private String dni;
   private String address;
   private String mail;
   private String phone;
   private String linkedln;
   private String state;
   private String rating;
   private String availability;
   private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>()
   ...  
   }
  ```